# Optimization suggestions for T-SQL Database and/or query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to find ways to reduce the time required to execute this query.  Right now, it takes anywhere from 30-90 minutes depending on the server.  I'm still learning about indexes so that's an option for future projects, and I'm also looking for suggestions that might help optimize the query itself.  The databases are pretty large, containing anywhere from 10-100 million rows in the main table.  Any suggestions would be helpful!

(I've changed column names to be more descriptive for this post)

```
USE MyDB
DECLARE @interval int = 6 
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MIN(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0) FROM MyTable1)
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MAX(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0) FROM MyTable1)
DECLARE @end DATETIME     = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,GETDATE())/@interval*@interval, 0))

--=========================================================
--   Update all DATEADD statements to desired interval
--=========================================================
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 
            [StartTime]  = CONVERT(datetime,@mindate),
            [EndTime]    = DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, CONVERT(datetime,@mindate))
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 
            DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [StartTime]),
            DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [EndTime])
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  [EndTime] < @end)
--==========================================================
SELECT 
    [ServerName]     = ServerName,
    [StartTime]      = CONVERT(varchar, [StartTime], 121),
    [EndTime]        = CONVERT(varchar, [EndTime], 121),
    [ItemsMigrated]  = COUNT(ItemIDColumn),
    [SizeMigrated]   = ISNULL(SUM(ItemSizeColumn),0),
    [ItemsFailed]    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable2 WHERE ItemStatusColumn = "Failed")
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN MyTable1 cr ON cr.DateColumn >= [StartTime] AND cr.DateColumn < [EndTime]
GROUP BY cte.StartTime, cte.EndTime
ORDER BY cte.StartTime
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: did you check the execution plan? and what indexes you have created so far?

Comment: try materializing the cte to a #temp

Comment: And this is crazy "[ItemsFailed]    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable2 WHERE ItemStatusColumn = "Failed")"  Why not just calculate that once?

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/) for tips on improving the performance of the CTE. What is a typical date range for your query?

Comment: Can you give a list of the requirements -- what exactly are you trying to do?  It looks like you are doing lots of stuff that can be done simply but it is so obtuse I'm not sure what the goal is.  For example -- you are rounding down to the nearest 6 hour mark?  Then getting min and max?

Comment: @FLICKER I haven't really checked the execution plan.  I'm still learning about how to utilize it.  Any resources you could recommend to learn how to get the most out of it?

Comment: @Paparazzi What sort of advantage would sending the cte to #temp offer?  Wouldn't the table still have to be constructed, so the time wouldn't be improved?  Also, good catch on the [ItemsFailed] subquery.  Fixed that.  Thanks!

Comment: @HABO I'll read that article.  Thanks for the link.  Typical date range is only a few (2-4) days at a time, but can range up to several months.  I think our oldest one that we're monitoring regularly goes back to May of 2015.

Comment: M-A-T-E-R-I-A-L-I-Z-E-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a select statement that iterates over the entire dataset:

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MIN(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0) FROM MyTable1)
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MAX(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0) FROM MyTable1)
```

can be

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME

SELECT @mindate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MIN(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0), 
       @maxdate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,MAX(DateColumn))/@interval*@interval, 0)
FROM MyTable1
```

In addition, the casting a datetime to a datetime will have no effect, the compiler will ignore that that but you are casating a datetime to a varchar for every row.  This will add up with 100 million rows.
Instead do it once since these datetimes don't change.

```
SELECT 
  [StartTime]  = CONVERT(datetime,@mindate),
  [EndTime]    = DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, CONVERT(datetime,@mindate))
  [StartTimeS]  = CONVERT(varchar, @mindate, 121),
  [EndTimeS]    =  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, CONVERT(datetime,@mindate)), 121),
  [ItemsFailed] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable2 WHERE ItemStatusColumn = "Failed")
UNION ALL

SELECT 
  DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [StartTime]),
  DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [EndTime])
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [StartTime]), 121),
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(HOUR, @interval, [EndTime]), 121),
  [ItemsFailed]
FROM   cte
```

Then you have

```
SELECT 
  [ServerName]     = ServerName,
  [StartTime]      = StartTimeS,
  [EndTime]        = EndTimeS,
  [ItemsMigrated]  = COUNT(ItemIDColumn),
  [SizeMigrated]   = ISNULL(SUM(ItemSizeColumn),0),
  [ItemsFailed]
```

But remember, 100m rows is still 100m rows, it will take some time.  If you are doing any joining you will need an index not to have a crazy performance hit.

(For example a join to a 10 row table without an index will cause 1 billion additional reads on your DB.)

Make some indexes if you have 100 million rows.

Comment: I implemented your changes and some suggested by @Reboon and the query went from ~20 minutes to ~8 minutes.  Big help!  Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1):

1.
As already mentioned by someone else, the following statement you can execute one and store it in a variable or join it as sub-query. The way you did it currently (at least from my experience), it will be execute row every row you are returning which will definitely slow down your query.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable2 WHERE ItemStatusColumn = "Failed")
```

2.
Then the following conversion you do not need, if you @Mindate is already a datetime.

```
CONVERT(datetime,@mindate)
```

3.
As already mentioned by someone else, load your CTE into a temp-table or table variable. Important, set which columns are NULL / NOT NULL as well as which one is the primary key (if possible) as this will speed up things.

4.
A little detail, but does @interval needs to be int? I am pretty sure you can use tinyint as datatype instead of int.

5.
Depending on your table MyTable1 you can use "with (nolock)" which can sometimes increase the performance a lot depending on your situation. But be very careful as "with (nolock)" you might get incomplete data if there are a lot of inserts/updates/deletes going on during you try at access the table. If this is your staging table where you are the only one accessing the table, it might be safe to use "with (nolock)" to speed up things.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/

Comment: 1. Good point.  Added.  2. There are several CONVERT statements scattered through the query.  To be honest, most of them are copy/paste from another member of my team.  I'm currently testing without them to make sure the data still comes out right.  3. I'll look into the temp table and see what kind of gains it will add.  4. Could go to tinyint.  Shouldn't ever need a value higher than 255 anyway.  I'll do that.  5. This query should be pulling data that has already been committed, so this might work.  However, it is the table where all our migration writes are happening.  I'll look into it.